# How to use paypal-report gem in my views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, paypal, report

I want to make PayPal reports working.

User when he sign up entering his PayPal email and password. So I need to storage it, to use it later, yes ?

I found this gem - > https://github.com/rngtng/paypal-report. I can't get how to use it.

I added line

```
require 'paypal/report'
```

in my merchants_controller.

and in documentation says:

```
  require 'paypal/report'
  api = Paypal::Report.new(user, password, vendor, partner)
  puts api.daily.inspect
```

I want to add in my merchants.show.erb, something like:

```
  <%= api(@user.paypal_email, @user.paypal_password).daily.inspect %>
```

So I can't call from view ? If user veryficated account (this gem used https://github.com/moshbit/paypal_permissions) is it easier or I should only storage PayPal login data ?

Comment: I cannot comment on the rest of the question, but: DO NOT STORE USER'S PAYPAL ACCOUNT INFORMATION! There has to be another way to authenticate with paypal, e.g. oauth. I would consider anything that has a user input his/her paypal account information as highly unprofessional. The only place where users should enter this information is an offical Paypal service.

Comment: So I should redirect them into PayPal service every time ? If user gives me PayPal permissions I can show him his reports ?

Comment: This is why there has to be another way to authenticate. You should never ever be forced to store a user password in plain text in order to be able to authenticate them later on (even if the API password is different from the normal PayPal account of a user). It should work like this: User is redirected (from your website) to Paypal authentication site -> they authenticate with username and password -> user is redirected back to your website and you receive a token that you can store to authenticate the user later on. I am not familiar with Paypal API - so just a general thought.

Comment: ok, I have token, thanks to paypal_permissions gem. Now I need help with Rails. You can't help with this , yes ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I guess the preferable solution would be to perform all actions within the controller and assign the results to instance variables which you can use in your view. This way caching & testing would be much easier. Example:

```
require 'paypal/report'

class MerchantsController
  def show
    api = Paypal::Report.new(user, password, vendor, partner)   
    @daily_stats = api.daily
  end
end
```

and the view (very rough idea only, please adapt to the correct data structure):

```
 <ul>
  <% @daily_stats.each do |stats| %>
   <li><%= stats %></li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
```

I hope this helps..

BTW: meanwhile we're getting our paypal reports from the SFTP server, which are way may complete, faster and easier to process..